# Is windows.setTimeout function getting executed in following code?

Tags: php

I want 3 elements of array to be displayed before setTimeout(30000) function and 3 elements after it;so that there is gap of 30 seconds between both the loops.But I am not getting the desired result.Following is the code:

```
<?php
$info=array(array("name"=>"abc",
              "phone"=>"12345"),
        array("name"=>"pqr",
              "phone"=>"23456"),
        array("name"=>"def",
              "phone"=>"34567"),
        array("name"=>"asd",
              "phone"=>"45678"),
        array("name"=>"ghj",
              "phone"=>"56789"),
        array("name"=>"jkl",
              "phone"=>"67566"),
        );
  echo ( $info[0]["name"]);
?>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>phone<th>
</tr>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($info as $data) {
    if($i==4)
    {

         break;

    } 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["phone"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++;}?>
<script>
  window.setTimeout(30000);
</script>
<?php
 for($j=3;$j<6;$j++)
    {
       ?>
             <tr>
             <td><?php echo $j+1; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $info[$j]["name"]; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $info[$j]["phone"]; ?></td>
             </tr> 
        <?php } ?>          
</table>
```

Comment: [This might help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: quite normal, you are mixing php and javascript. PHP runs on server, javascript on client. Your 30secs delay is on client. You can't do what you want with PHP.

Comment: What you can do is put the two PHP loops in different files. Start with the first file, and then wait, like you did and call the second file using ajax. There's also an ugly way: using `sleep()` in PHP, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php but this will keep the connection open and you probable need to flush the output buffer to see the output of the first loop. Also make sure your maximum execution time > 30 secs.